# Android Fragments - How can I keep the data?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using a ViewPager with multiple Fragments. (Tab navigation + swipe).
In my first ListFragment I'm displaying a list of data with a custom adapter.

The problem is, when swipping to Tab #3 and then back, my ArrayList has size 0.

How can I keep all the data of a Fragment in memory? I don't want to read it again from the database, all I want is that when returning to this fragment everything should stay the same...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. host the data in the container activity and access to that from the fragment
2. use a singleton object / some class hosted in the application class

But bear in mind that whenever your process get killed you will loose the data in any case. If you want the data to persist across multiple process spawn you need to store it into sqllite / some kind of persistence.

Comment: Yes, I already have all the data in a local database. So I guess I'll use the activity to save it temporarily, I thought maybe the fragment has some way of doing it itself. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In [fragment guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) FragmentList example you can find:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    }
```

Which you can use later like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }
}
```

I'm a beginner in Fragments but it seems like solution of your problem ;) **onActivityCreated** is invoked after fragment returns from back stack.